# Transmission daemon stopped working - owner or permission issue?

Tags: pi-3, permissions

Suddenly I'm having issues starting downloads.

I'm using : `sudo service transmission-daemon (start/stop/restart)`

I looked at `/var/log/daemon.log` and found an error:

```
Couldn't save temporary file "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/resume/(torrentName)": Permission denied (variant.c:1227)
Unable to save resume file: Permission denied (torrent.c:536)
Couldn't save temporary file "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/torrents/(torrentName)": Permission denied (variant.c:1227)
```

Looking at those dirs are both empty with the same permissions:

```
$ ls -la /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/torrents/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 transmission        transmission        4096 Oct  4  2016 .
drwsrwxr-x 5 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Apr  1 18:30 ..
```

Looking at the process owner:

```
$ ps -aux | grep trans
debian-+  1900  0.0  0.6  29196  5796 ?        Ssl  18:33   0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a whim, I tried changing the owner of the `resume` directory:

```
sudo chown debian-transmission:debian-transmission /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/resume
```

That did the trick.  Parent directory's owner was debian-transmission and `debian-+` was listed as the user of the daemon.  I'm not 100% sure why this fixed it, but things are back up and running again.

Comment: Please accept your answer. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again months for months.